# How to add csv files to a pandas dataframe present in Azure file share using python

Tags: python, pandas, azure

I have the following code which displays the csv files present in the folder of Azure file share

```
from azure.storage.file import FileService

file_service = FileService(account_name='storage_account_name', account_key='key')

generator = file_service.list_directories_and_files('path/../..')
for file_or_dir in generator:
    print(file_or_dir.name)
```

However, I want to store the csv files in a pandas dataframe and do further operations. Can anyone please help me how to access the csv files and add them in dataframe

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to read the csv files using `pd.read_csv(< FileName >)`. Below is the complete code that worked for me.

```
from  azure.storage.file  import  FileService

import  pandas  as  pd

file_service = FileService(account_name='<ACCOUNT_NAME>', account_key='<ACCOUNT_KEY>')

generator = file_service.list_directories_and_files('fileshare/')

for  file_or_dir  in  generator:
    print(file_or_dir.name)
    getfile=file_service.get_file_to_path(share_name='fileshare',directory_name='',file_path=file_or_dir.name,file_name=file_or_dir.name)
    df=pd.read_csv(file_or_dir.name)
    print(df)
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]